# jQuery Function Stuck in Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple div with a link with in:

```
<div class="mhButton">
    <a href="#" id="RegisterAnimal"><span class="icon-checkmark"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Register Animal</a>
</div>
```

I've have a function that is triggered whenever the 'div.mhButton' is clicked. This function should find 'div.mhButton' child 'a' and click it.

```
    $(".mhButton").on('click', function () {
        var a = $(this).find("a").text();
        console.log(a);
        $(this).find("a").click();
    });
```

This works, however, I get stuck in a loop that runs like 639 times.

I can't comprehend why this runs X amount of times, then continues without error.

Does anyone have a solution on how to prevent this? Along with an explanation on why this happens?

Note* The console is logging the same button, again and again.

Comment: Why do you do `.off().click()`?

Comment: Was trying to remove the event handler off the click, updated the queestion with the correct code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Probably because you are triggering the click of the anchor when the container is clicked, and then when the anchor is clicked, the container click is triggered and so on, so it becomes circular. Why don't you just bind the container to the anchor handler and do a stopPropagation

Comment: What happens when you add the ol' `e.preventDefault()` within the function?

Comment: @ckpepper02 preventDefault prevents the default action, which is to follow a link, that would not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `a` tag is embedded in the button, you are continuously re-firing the event. Events will bubble up, so the anchor will get clicked, and then its parent. It is running until the browser gets tired of running it and then it just stops. The method doesn't actually do anything which is likely why you aren't seeing any issues. You can accomplish your goal a couple of ways:

```
$(".mhButton").click(function () {
    $(this).off('click'); // turn the click handler off in the handler itself. 
    var a = $(this).find("a").text();
    console.log(a);
    $(this).find("a").click();
});
```

If you do this, then you will end up only being able to fire the event once.

Alternatively:

```
$(".mhButton").click(function (e) {
    a = $(this).find("a").text();
    console.log(a);
    $(this).find("a").click();
});

$("#RegisterAnimal").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the anchor from re-firing the button click
});
```

Altenatively, you can just style the link to look like a button and avoid the unnecessary click handlers all together.

Comment: @JuanMendes ...which is exactly what it say right after the code :p

Comment: @Mark The only problem with your approach that works is because there may be a click event on the document that will never fire. That is often the case with menus and popups that should be dismissed when you click somewhere else on the page. Using the `stopPropagation` approach would not hide the menu.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$(this).find("a").click();` the event will bubble up to the `div.mhButton` tag and cause your handler to be called again. The reason it runs around 500 times is because it stops with a stack overflow, it does not continue

You can prevent it by checking if the click was the `<a>` tag itself and not calling `click()` in that case

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/zdkrhh42/

**Note Regarding the accepted answer**

Bic's second answer almost works, mine is a different approach with fewer side effects. The main problem with calling `stopPropagation` is that there may be handlers on the whole document that wouldn't get fired in that case. A commmon case is when you have a menu or a dialog that is supposed to hide when you click anywhere else on the page. The `stopPropagation` approach will prevent the menu from being hidden when they click your button.

```
$(".mhButton").click(function (e) {       
    // Only run this handler if the click was on the div, not the link itself 
    if ( $(e.target).is('a, a *') ) {
        return;
    }
    var a = $(this).find("a").text();
    $(this).find("a").click();
});
```

Comment: How does that prevent it though? I need to click it.

Comment: @Mark why do you need to click it?  Can't you just set `window.location.href` to the desired URL ?

Comment: Because it is actually triggering a ajax call.

Comment: See my update, calling `click()` causes your handler to be called again